# any way to transfer output of a python script directly into a .txt file

Tags: python

Hi I find it tedious to call the function to verify primacy of numbers especially when I am dealing with large numbers > few millions. I would like to know if there is a way I can generate primes up to say a billion and copy the output into a .txt file directly even as the primes are being crunched in python? thank you.

Comment: Do you mean real-time output transfer?  Like that you can see happen?

Comment: I wish people wouldn't down-vote your question. The lame egos on SO don't like to help newbies. I hate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming unix:

```
python myprogram.py > outputfile.txt
```

Is the standard output redirection. Or you can write out to a file:

```
def writeout(output):
    f = open('file.txt', 'w')
    f.write(output)
    f.close()
```